# Failed to convert server response to JSON | gcloud.services.operations.describe

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm new to google cloud services. I was going through some tutorials and I had to run the following command in order to describe an operation.

```
$ gcloud services operations describe operations/acf.xxxx
```

however, this command has failed with the error stating:

> **ERROR: (gcloud.services.operations.describe) INTERNAL: Failed to convert server response to JSON**

I'm performing these operations in windows PowerShell using bash commands. Is there any solution to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try to use 'gcloud beta services operations describe' ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug.

I get the same error on Linux with gcloud v.291.0.0.

You may wish to report this issue at Google's [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

A useful feature of `gcloud` is that you can append any command with `--log-http` to see the underlying REST API calls which is often (not really in this case) more illuminating of the error.

This yields (for me):

```
uri: https://serviceconsumermanagement.googleapis.com/v1beta1/operations/${OPERATION_ID}?alt=json
method: GET
...
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Failed to convert server response to JSON",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Another excellent (debugging) tool is APIs Explorer that supports all Google's REST endpoints. This is  accessible from API documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-consumer-management/reference/rest/v1beta1/operations/get

If you complete the APIs Explorer (form) on the righthand side, I suspect, you'll receive the same error.

The approaches appear to confirm that the issue is Google-side.